# In excel, how to horizontally sort based off of a separate column, and remove the horizontal duplicates

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to take a list of keys and horizontally list them based on the a quantity column which will always be either 1 or much greater than 1. Currently the keys are placed horizontally by their matching key, but I would like to add the additional sort by quantity and remove horizontal duplicates parameters.

Example of base dataset

[image]

What I currently have done

[image]

This is done using

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B:$B,AGGREGATE(15,7,ROW($A$2:$A$14)/($A$2:$A$14=$E2),COLUMN(A1))),"")
```

What I would like to end with

[image]

Comment: sort your data on column C and change `($A$2:$A$14=$E2)` to `(($A$2:$A$14=$E2)*(COUNTIFS($E2:E2,$B$2:$B$14)=0))` and `COLUMN(A1)` to `1`: `=IFERROR(INDEX($B:$B,AGGREGATE(15,7,ROW($A$2:$A$14)/(($A$2:$A$14=$E2)*(COUNTIFS($E2:E2,$B$2:$B$14)=0)),1)),"")`

Comment: I am struggling a bit with the second part of this answer, when I replace COLUMN(A1) I get blank cells, is this how you meant it to be formatted? =IFERROR(INDEX($B:$B,AGGREGATE(15,7,ROW($A$2:$A$14)/($A$2:$A$14=$E2),IFERROR(INDEX($B:$B,AGGREGATE(15,7,ROW($A$2:$A$14)/(($A$2:$A$14=$E2)*(COUNTIFS($E2:E2,$B$2:$B$14)=0)),1)),""))),"")

Comment: no just: `=IFERROR(INDEX($B:$B,AGGREGATE(15,7,ROW($A$2:$A$14)/(($A$2:$A$14=$E2)*(COUNTIFS($E2:E2,$B$2:$B$14)=0)),1)),"")`

Comment: I see now, thanks a bunch for the help!

Answer (score 1):

This is my try using **Excel 365**:

In cell `E2` enter the following formula to return a unique list of Key1:

```
=UNIQUE(A2:A14,0)
```

There is no need to drag down the formula as the result will "SPILL" to a range of rows.

In Cell `F2`, enter the following formula and drag it down to apply across:

```
=UNIQUE(INDEX(TRANSPOSE(SORT(FILTER(B2:C14,A2:A14=E2),2,-1)),1),1)
```

[image: screenshot - solution]

The formulas used, such as **UNIQUE**, **FILTER** and **SORT**, are self-explanatory (Exceljet.net has ample examples of using these formulas). I used **TRANSPOSE** to display the sister keys in a row, and the use of **INDEX** is to select the Key2 range after filtering range `B2:C14` (which is a range combining Key2 and Qty).